# Keep exponents separately

Tags: pattern-matching

I have the following expressions $g^{ab+cd+...}$ or in the full form `Power[g,Plus[Times[a,b],Times[c,d],...]]`

How to convert this expression into

`Power[g,Times[a,b]]Power[g,Times[c,d]]...`?

Here $...$ could be either nothing or one more, but of course it would be nice to get the most general expression for any number of terms.

Comment: Sometimes Maple is better, but I already solved the problem. At first `x = FullForm[expr1 /. Plus -> List]` and then `FullForm[x[[1,1]]] FullForm[x[[1,2]]]`, etc. It was better for me to keep everything in the full form.

Answer (score 2):

These forms are equivalent from mathematics point of view. So if you want to *display* exponents separately you can use

```
MakeBoxes[Power[z_, Plus@x__], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[SuperscriptBox[ToBoxes@z, ToBoxes@#] & /@ {x}]

g^(a b + c d)
```

[image]

You can evaluate `Clear[MakeBoxes]` to get back the default formatting.

If you want to keep them separately for a further *pattern-matching* you can freely use a custom function

```
pow[z_, x__Plus] := Times @@ (pow[z, #] & /@ x)

g^(a b + c d) /. Power -> pow
```

[image]

```
% /. pow -> Power
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
expr1 = Power[g, Plus[Times[a, b], Times[c, d]]];
Times @@ Defer /@ (expr1 /. Plus -> List)
(* or Times @@ HoldForm /@ (expr1 /. Plus -> List) *)
```

[image]

In version 10, you can also use

```
Inactive[Times]@@ (expr1 /. Plus -> List)
```

Comment: I need to keep the result in the full form, but if I use one of the suggested methods then the result would contain either `HoldForm` or `Inactive[Times]`, which I want to avoid. Is there any other way to keep the expression in the full form like this `Power[g,Times[a,b]]Power[g,Times[c,d]]...`?

Comment: @g3n1uss, i don't know of any other way to prevent `Power[g,Times[a,b]]Power[g,Times[c,d]]` from evaluating into `Power[g, Plus[Times[a, b], Times[c, d]]]`.

Comment: I can do smth like this. At first `x = FullForm[expr1 /. Plus -> List]` and then `FullForm[x[[1,1]]]` `FullForm[x[[1,2]]]`, etc